# new Google spreadsheet #REF converting from old Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have been converting some of my old Google spreadsheets to the new one recently released. The people at Google tell you to copy over the sheets from the old sheet into a new spreadsheet.

The problem I'm experiencing is: 
after you copy all your sheets over to the new spreadsheet, then you rename the tabs back to the original names, e.g. get rid of the "copy of" infront of the name, all formulas that have a reference to another sheet will be a "#REF". To fix it is easy, you just go to the cell and hit `F2` then `ENTER`. The problem is I have tons and tons of link. It would take me a long time to convert each sheet and manually reset all of the "#REF"s everywhere. Does anybody know how to do it all at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A Google engineer helped on this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/mfm4r43tGgg/lPHYFxy34SYJ).

You have to figure out the best order to copy the sheets over in. Copy the sheet that has the fewest references to other sheets first. If the exact sheet name isn't there when you copy over a sheet with a link it will raise a #REF error, so where possible make sure the referenced sheet is in the new sheet with the exact name before copying over.

Comment: This is a major problem with migrating to the new Google Spreadsheets. Can you elaborate on your final solution please?

Comment: basically you have to figure out the order to copy the sheets over. Copy the sheet that has the least links to other sheets. If the exact sheet name isn't there when you copy over a sheet with a link, it will ref. So make sure the referenced sheet is in the new sheet with the exact name before copying over.